# What is a good way to "cache" / "index" data that cannot be indexed through a normal index / indexed view?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I'm looking for a performant way to cache / index data that cannot be done through a persisted computed column & standard index, or an indexed view, because it contains a CTE / non-deterministic function.

The simplest way I can think to explain it, would be something like a hierarchical structure, where a decendant lower in the structure, needs to persist a value from a higher ancestor.

The table and it's data would look something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES](
    [CODE] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,               -- The unique code of the level.
    [PARENT] nvarchar(10) NULL,                 -- The code of the parent level.
    [TYPE] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,               -- The type of level.
    [TYPEDESC] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,           -- The description of the type.
    CONSTRAINT [PRIK_TESTSTRUCTURES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
    (
        [CODE] ASC
    )
    WITH ( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
    ON [PRIMARY]
    ) 
ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES]
( [CODE], [PARENT], [TYPE], [TYPEDESC] )
VALUES 
( N'10001', Null, N'Level 1', N'I am a tree' ),
( N'10002', N'10001', N'Level 2', N'I prefer to swim' ),
( N'10003', N'10002', N'Level 3', N'Apples taste like gummy bears' ),
( N'10004', N'10003', N'Level 4', N'I enjoy hiking' ),
( N'10005', N'10004', N'Level 5', N'I am a stone' );
GO
```

A function to get the characteristics of an ancestor could then look like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]
(
    @Code nvarchar(10), -- The code to anchor to.
    @Type nvarchar(10)  -- The type being sought.
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    WITH CTE ( [CODE], [PARENT], [TYPE], [TYPEDESC], [DEPTH] ) AS
    (
        SELECT [CODE], [PARENT], [TYPE], [TYPEDESC], 1 AS [DEPTH]
        FROM [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES]
        WHERE [CODE] = @Code

        UNION ALL

        SELECT [STRUCT].[CODE], [STRUCT].[PARENT], [STRUCT].[TYPE], [STRUCT].[TYPEDESC], CTE.[DEPTH] + 1
        FROM [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES] [STRUCT]
        INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.[PARENT] = [STRUCT].[CODE]
        WHERE CTE.[TYPE] != @Type
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE [TYPE] = @Type;
GO
```

Running the following script would give a sample of what the data would look like that I'm trying to persist, namely the 2 linkages.

```
SELECT [STRUCTURE].*, [KEY1].[TYPEDESC] AS [Key Linkage 1], [KEY2].[TYPEDESC] AS [Key Linkage 2]
FROM [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES] [STRUCTURE]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]( [STRUCTURE].[CODE], N'Level 1' ) [KEY1]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]( [STRUCTURE].[CODE], N'Level 3' ) [KEY2]
WHERE [STRUCTURE].[CODE] = N'10004';
```

Linkage 1 and 2 are definitely deterministic, but due to the CTE, sql server sees it automatically as non-deterministic.

```
CODE       PARENT     TYPE       TYPEDESC           Key Linkage 1       Key Linkage 2
10004      10003      Level 4    I enjoy hiking     I am a tree         Apples taste like gummy bears
```

Effectively, if the "type" of the ancestor changes, the decendant would need to reflect this change:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES]
SET [TYPEDESC] = N'Jack met Jill on the hill'
WHERE [CODE] = N'10001';

UPDATE [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES]
SET [TYPEDESC] = N'Look under the stone'
WHERE [CODE] = N'10003';

SELECT [STRUCTURE].*, [KEY1].[TYPEDESC] AS [Key Linkage 1], [KEY2].[TYPEDESC] AS [Key Linkage 2]
FROM [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES] [STRUCTURE]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]( [STRUCTURE].[CODE], N'Level 1' ) [KEY1]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]( [STRUCTURE].[CODE], N'Level 3' ) [KEY2]
WHERE [STRUCTURE].[CODE] = N'10004';
```

Looking up the same record, would now result in this:

```
CODE       PARENT     TYPE       TYPEDESC           Key Linkage 1                  Key Linkage 2
10004      10003      Level 4    I enjoy hiking     Jack met Jill on the hill      Look under the stone
```

An additional requirement, would be to be able to search on these linkages, to find all records that have the same ancestor:

```
SELECT [STRUCTURE].*, [KEY1].[TYPEDESC] AS [Key Linkage 1], [KEY2].[TYPEDESC] AS [Key Linkage 2]
FROM [dbo].[TESTSTRUCTURES] [STRUCTURE]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]( [STRUCTURE].[CODE], N'Level 1' ) [KEY1]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GETSTRUCTUREBYTYPE]( [STRUCTURE].[CODE], N'Level 3' ) [KEY2]
WHERE [KEY2].[TYPEDESC] = N'Look under the stone';
```

which would result in this:

```
CODE       PARENT     TYPE       TYPEDESC               Key Linkage 1                  Key Linkage 2
10003      10002      Level 3    Look under the stone   Jack met Jill on the hill      Look under the stone
10004      10003      Level 4    I enjoy hiking         Jack met Jill on the hill      Look under the stone
10005      10004      Level 5    I am a stone           Jack met Jill on the hill      Look under the stone
```

Now all of this works just fine on smaller data sets, but on larger datasets (we need to support tens of millions of records), performance will obviously end up dropping.

I'm looking for a way to "persist" the data until it changes, perhaps something that mimics SQL Servers way of managing it's indexes; which determines when they're out of date, and updates them?

Hoping someone has some more experience on this than I do and would appreciate your insights.

Comment: Have you considered using stored procedures (SPs), or triggers, to maintain a separate table that reflects the desired relations? If you restrict create/update/delete operations so that they _must_ be performed using SPs then the SPs can perform the specified action and then, in the same transaction, update the relationship table with the knowledge of precisely which data have changed. There may be other security and maintenance benefits to blocking ad-hoc changes and limiting write access to SPs.

Comment: For your specific example, are you aware of [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) data type? It would allow you to materialize the hierarchy and avoid the recursive query to determine it a run time.

Comment: @HABO yes, I am strongly considering a fixed column with triggers to update the data, but was hoping for a something within SQL Server that could help, hence why I'm asking here, hoping to get more ideas before making a decision.

Comment: @BenThul yes, I'm aware of it the `hierarchyid` data type, we're planning our migration to it.  Though I'm unsure of how that would assist?  Would appreciate more insight if you'd be willing to share.

Comment: I read your problem as "how do I materialize the hierarchy such that it is runtime efficient?" and hierarchyid will help with that. Using your example, you want to find ancestors for a given node that have "Level 1" and "Level 3" as their description. hierarchyid makes finding ancestors for a given node trivial. And, because it's indexable, you can put a composite index on that column along with the description (either as a key or include column) and the engine should have no problem finding the relevant nodes.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks! Wasn't aware that hierarchyid would improve the performance THAT much. Going to take a look at that and report back.